# What does layering biryani actually do?

Tags: rice, indian-cuisine

I've recently been experimenting with biryani (mostly chicken hyderabadi) and one thing that sort of puzzles me is making layers of rice (as typically instructed in recipes) as opposed to just having mixed rice over the chicken, even when each layer is topped the same way (ghee, herbs, biryani masala, saffron milk, fried onion). What is actually going on here and why does it make a difference? I would think that a haphazard mix of rice, spices and fried onions would achieve basically the same thing. You might not mix it too thoroughly so that you still get some unevenness like you would with layers. The steam should also still distribute unevenly the same way as it gets more trapped at the bottom, I guess. The final dish that is served is also not really "layered" in the same way as e.g. lasagne, so it's not like it's a textural or structural thing either.

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/121623/67

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From what I understand, biryani is never stirred except at the end when it is served.

Part of the reasons for not stirring is that traditionally during the second stage of cooking, the partially cooked rice is finally baked and steamed in a sealed pot. Prior to this, the rice is often cooked in stock beforehand to add flavour, but again it is not stirred.

As moscafj has said, part of the appeal of a biryani is the crispy layer of rice at the bottom, which would be lost upon stirring. But layering has a much more important role to play in the biryani.

Part of the inherent problem with the dish is the large volume of bland rice versus meat. It is a difficult balance to season such a dish throughout properly with liquid, whilst maintaining the correct texture. Traditionally, the layers were very different ingredients and each layer was independently seasoned so that sufficient flavour was added to the rice. The difficulty here with the mixing method is if you add sufficient liquid to intensify the flavour, the rice will potentially be soggy and overcooked, which is what would happen if the starch was released from the rice by mixing or too much much liquid added.

By building the biryani in layers, and seasoning each layer as it is assembled, different flavours are absorbed by each layer. Every layer of rice can then maintain the required "Stiffness", as very little liquid is added, just sufficient to either be partially absorbed or steamed off. When assembling the dish the rice is always gently placed on top of the ingredients, and never pushed down, as this again could break the rice.

The ultimate test of a good biryani is separate, cooked pieces of rice that are well seasoned and flavoured independently of any other pieces of meat or vegetable etc. from the dish. With care, you could achieve this with a stirred mixture, but to do so consistently (as the properties of rice varies considerably with age and variety etc.) would be challenging.

Comment: Stirring also would mean that you no longer have as much variation in the dish— some cuisines really value there being multiple flavors / textures within a dish rather than it being completely homogeneous.

Comment: It’s also probably out of scope for discussion here, but there are cultures where people eat on a set order (male adults before women and children).  Layering would give the people eating first the option to select more protein or carbs instead of it being a fixed ratio in the whole dish.  Even without the cultural aspect, some people just prefer one more than the other

Comment: Also: depending on how you're serving it, the layers may still be separate when served.  Yes, it's common to dump everything out on a platter, but sometimes one carefully unmolds the biryani, or even serves it in the original cooking pot, so all the layers are intact.

Answer (score 5):

When I cook a biryani, my goal is to ultimately get a crusty rice layer on the bottom. I use a dutch oven. When ready I flip the biryani onto a serving platter (a tricky maneuver for sure), the crusty rice (with luck) is on top.  The layering simply serves to ensure that everything inside is evenly distributed, but that the rice layer is intact.  The desired crusty rice layer is the only reason I see to avoid mixing thoroughly in advance. It certainly won't impact the flavor or cooking, but you might not be able to achieve that even crust, which is my personal goal.

Comment: Isn't the meat usually "in the way" so that you don't really get a crusty layer by contact with the metal surface? Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but I'm not used to biryani being crusty, at least not like, say, Iranian tahdig. I'm also not really sure how mixing changes that. It is still just rice in the end, or are you avoiding getting onions and herbs in the way of your crusty rice?

Comment: @tmph I put a rice layer in the bottom of the dutch oven to start.  Then, proceed with layering.  I don't know if it is traditional, but I like the crusty rice, and it is the only reason I could think of for NOT mixing everything in advance.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but I've actually never come across a biryani like that. Sounds a lot like tahdig though, which is another dish I enjoy so worth a shot for sure!

Comment: @tmph...yes, I suppose I am really going for an Indian biryani with a tahdig-like crust...it never gets that evenly crusty, but any crunchiness is enjoyable.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a historical note, which supplements the other answers on this question:

Historically, Biryani only had two layers (see [video of making a 1500s biryani here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6Yr7sDofLc)).  It consisted of a meat stew (usually goat) with parboiled rice on top, cooked in a large pot over hot coals.  In order to have the rice steam properly, it had to remain mostly above the stew. The wet stew could handle long, hot cooking. Rice grains which dropped to the bottom of the pot (or were mixed in) would turn to mush or burn.

The many-layered biryanis we see today are descendants of that early version.  In some cases, the layering probably is actually an affectation, and doesn't affect the taste/texture much if the biryani is being scooped out onto a platter. But in other cases, it might change the final result.